# Git checkout to a tag after clone gives error

Tags: git, git-tag

I successfully cloned a branch `branchX` on a remote git repo and wanted to use a code base at a certain tag `tagX`. I did as mentioned [here](https://coderwall.com/p/k2fisg/git-clone-a-repository-and-checkout-a-specified-tag) to checkout to the tag. But it gives me the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'tagX' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How to resolve this error? Is there an alternative way to point to the tag?

Comment: Execute `git tag` command and check whether the tag is on the list.

Comment: Did you use the option `--single-branch`?

Comment: @ElpieKay Nope. I didn't. I used `git clone <repo> --branch branchX` to clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch all tags from the remote.
Execute the command `git fetch --tags` and then try to check out.

Comment: Yes. When you checkout to a tag, Git will move the HEAD position to an old commit. That is why it says "the HEAD is detached".

Comment: So, if I want to make changes, I have to create a new branch and merge? Is that the only solution?

Comment: What you can do is create a new branch using `git checkout -b feature/something`. Then you will have a new branch which is based on the commit referenced by the tag. Then the head will move to the new branch. It won't be a detached state.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit You *could* commit from this detached HEAD state, without branching, and merge later into an existing branch, but there's no reason *not* to create a branch, since it's their very purpose (at virtually no cost).